# Why I don't get instance of paired device via CoreBluetooth?

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth, external-accessory

I have a device (named later "scanner") and other devices (named later "stone"). Scanner can scan stones and display their information on build in display. Scanner can send stones information via Bluetooth and I want to read this data and use it in my app. I started code connection implementation but I discovered a problem. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class BluetoothViewController: UIViewController {

    var manager:CBCentralManager!
    var peripheral:CBPeripheral!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }
}

extension BluetoothViewController: CBCentralManagerDelegate {

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state == .poweredOn {
            central.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
        }
        else {
            print("Bluetooth not available.")
        }
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        print("peripheral \(peripheral)")
        print("rssi \(RSSI)")
        print("advertisementData: \(advertisementData)")
        print("--------")
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        print(peripheral)
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didFailToConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
        print(peripheral)
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
        print(peripheral)
    }
}

extension BluetoothViewController: CBPeripheralDelegate {

}
```

The problem is scanner doesn't appear in

`func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber)`

and

`func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral)`

never call.

Note that my iPhone is connected with a scanner and scanner tell me the connection is working.

## What I want to achieve?

I want to create viewcontroller which check if scanner is connected.

```
if connected then
    get scan information
else
    find device and connect
get scan information
```

Please help me. :)

## Edit

In [LightBlue Explorer app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lightblue-explorer-bluetooth/id557428110?mt=8) my scanner device doesn't appear.
But with this [app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/allflex-smart-list/id1106877054?mt=8) works perfectly.

Maybe using CoreBluetooth is a wrong way to do this. What is better. If creators of above app can communicate thee is a possibility to do it.

Comment: Is your scanner device advertising a BLE service?  Try the LightBlue app from the app store.

Comment: @Paulw11 what if no?

Comment: You need to explicitly connect to the peripheral in `didDiscoverPeripheral` in order for the `didConnect` method to be called. Not sure why your device isn't being discovered though. What exactly are these "stones"?

Comment: Stone are irrelevant. I want to connect my device with scanner but it does not appear in `didDiscoverPeripheral`

Comment: @KamilHarasimowicz If LightBlue doesn't see it then it isn't a BLE peripheral (or it isn't advertising a gatt service)

Comment: @Paulw11 so how this second app works?

Comment: The manual for the device indicates that it uses iPod Accessory Protocol, so the device is under the MFi program. That means it uses the external accessory framework and legacy Bluetooth.

Comment: @Paulw11 you have right. I posted an answer according your information. Tnx for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Paulw11's comment I realized my "scanner" uses iPod Accessory Protocol. To make sure I import `ExternalAccessory` framework and check for devices.

```
    EAAccessoryManager.shared().showBluetoothAccessoryPicker(withNameFilter: nil, completion: nil)
```

After call this function I saw list of accessory devices and my scanner was there.